# Bash errexit with arithmetic expansion

Tags: bash

I have the following Bash script called `errexit`:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -ex
a=$1
((a++))
echo $a
```

When I run it with the argument "0", it triggers the error exit:

```
$ ./errexit 0; echo $?
+ a=0
+ (( a++ ))
1
```

But when I run it with the argument "1", it does not trigger the error exit:

```
$ ./errexit 1; echo $?
+ a=1
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 2
2
0
```

I do not understand, why 2 is not interpreted as false, although it is the case in an `if` statement:

```
$ if grep nix nix; then echo $?=t; else echo $?=f; fi
grep: nix: No such file or directory
2=f
```

Can anybody explain why the arithmetic expansion behaves differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Bash manual:

> ((expression))
>   The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION. If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".

So according to the *post-operator*. The value of `((a++))` when `a=0` is `0`. So the return status is 1.

```
a=0
echo $((a++))   # 0
```

Comment: `((expression))` is not the same as `$((expression))`

Comment: Yes, it is. But if you want to get the value of the expression `((expression))` you should do it with `$((expression))`.  @cdarke.

Comment: Uff. I was not aware that the post-operator even applies to return statements. But I tried it and it is even the same in C.

Comment: See my post, the difference between the two can give different `$?` results, which is what the question is about.

Comment: @cdarke. `a=$((a+1))` return status is `0` because the assignment returns `0`, is irrevelant to `$((..))`. For example: `a=$((0))` will cause return value 0 and `((0))` will cause return value 1.

Comment: I am sorry that someone downvoted your answer. But the other guys did not understand the problem.

Comment: @ceving, It does not matter. But I want to make my opinion clear. And I try to not misunderstand the problem.

Comment: @ceving: The duplicated answer makes sense?

Comment: @ceving. Yes, the *post-operator* and *pre-operator* works the same as C.